# Why we have to create personal access client in passport again and again

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm using passport in my laravel project for the first time. Whenever I start the project, entering the login credentials it gives me error:

> "Personal access client not found. Please create one."

then I run the command "`php artisan passport:install`" or "`php artisan passport:client --personal`" and everything runs well, but I want to fix this problem entirely.

How can I fix it?

Comment: i think may be it is due to migrating the tables..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run php artisan passport:client --personal" every time to generate a new token. Each time you do database migration you drop Oauth table as well.